# Taking lines with unknown location from one text file and place them in another

Tags: c#, wpf, text-files

I want to take the usernames in one textfile and place them in another, so that I have the original textfile with all the information and another textfile with just the usernames. Every day a new file with all usernames and their according groups gets generated, so it should be read from the most recent file.

Sadly, all usernames in the original text file are at unknown places, but there is one thing that seperates a username from a group information.

They all have a *[space]* in the line above them and a line with *"-----------------------------"* below them. Another problem that occurs is, that some usernames have e-Mail adresses below them, some don't.
So the only reliable source for checking if it is a username or not would be the *[space]* in the line above the username.

As it is a quite big file with about 700 usernames, writing them down all manually would be quite uncomfortable and is inconsiderable.

Example input file (there is a blank line at beginning but markdown does not show it):

```
User1
-----------------------------
Group1
Group3
Group4


User2
mail@mail.com
-----------------------------
Group2


User3
-----------------------------
exampleGroup
Potatoes
```

I really hope you can help me, as I am quite a beginner to coding.

---

**EDIT**

As stated by O. R. Mapper, this is not a "write a code for me"-service.

And I forgot to include my code, that I was trying to get it to work with.
Unfortunately it  didn't work. Here it is

```
     string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        path += "users.txt";
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            for (int zeileIndex = 0; zeileIndex < fileLines.Length; zeileIndex++)
             {
            string zeile = fileLines[zeileIndex];
            //zeile is simply a word for line in another language
            if (zeile.Contains(" "))
            {
                ++zeileIndex;
                if (zeile.Contains(" "))
                {
                    ++zeileIndex;
                    listboxNames.Items.Add(zeile);
                }
            }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Rather than giving link to complete file provide a short but sufficient example of its content.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" service. **However**, "beginner to coding" implies you want at some point be not-a-beginner-anymore to coding, and I think this is a good opportunity for you to progress a bit: You have already outlined your requirements quite well. Essentially, what you want to do is determine for each line whether it is a user name or not, and you have indicated the conditions. Could you try and write some code that 1) loads the file, 2) reads the lines e.g. into an array, 3) checks for each line, based on your conditions, whether it is a user name?

Comment: @Sinatr it's not the complete file. It's an example written in the style the original files are generated.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i added the code that I tried it with.

Comment: Your file isn't publicly accessible - Have you tried to debug your code step by step?

Comment: @PhilipW It is accessible now. Regarding the debugging. yes, i did

Comment: What you currently do is the following: If two consecutive lines contain a whitespace, add the thrid line to your list. Thats not what you want to do (obviously). Instead, for each line, get the content of the line and the content of the next 3 lines. If the first one contains a whitespace, and the third or forth the "-------------", add the second line to your list...

Comment: @PhilipW do you have a code example for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of one way to solve the problem. Incidentally, for a beginning programmer like yourself, I would recommend starting with a high-level language such as Python, as that lets you focus on programming concepts instead of things like low-level memory management and pointers.

I don't know C# so I didn't look at your code in any great detail.

Input data looks like this:

```
... other stuff ...
[space]
line with username
optional line with email address
------------ (some number of repeated hyphens)
... other stuff ...
```

In your sample file, [space] appears to mean an empty line, so I'll assume that.

I will assume that the [space] always comes before a username line, and never before anything else. I will also assume that the first line of the file is never a username line.

So, essentially we want to go through the lines, keeping track of when the previous line was empty. In pseudocode:

```
prev_empty = false
while (readline(line)):
    if line is empty:
        prev_empty = true
    else:
        if prev_empty:
            username = extract_uname(line)
            output(username)
            prev_empty = false
```

If you decide you also want to capture the email addresses, the logic becomes more complex, but you use essentially the same method: keep track of where you are in the file by using flags or other variables to track the state.